# Show admin configuration in airflow running on docker-compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose, configuration, airflow, admin

Does anybody know how to unblock admin>configuration in UI of airflow which is running with docker-compose?
When I try to open it it shows '# Your Airflow administrator chose not to expose the configuration, most likely for security reasons.'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set an environment variable `AIRFLOW__WEBSERVER__EXPOSE_CONFIG=True`.

Answer (score 1):

In Airflow 2.4.3, in the `[webserver]` section of `airflow.cfg`, change the property `expose_config` from the default `False` to `True` or `non-sensitive- only`, depending on what you want to expose to the UI users:

```
# Expose the configuration file in the web server. Set to "non-sensitive- only" to show all values
# except those that have security implications. "True" shows all values. "False" hides the
# configuration completely.
expose_config = False
```